# dplyr package in R: subset() function to subset the dataframe by month; Error -<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

**Problem Statement**

I have a data frame called **'New_Blue'** (see below) and I want to subset the data frame by month using the **'subset()'** function in the **'dplyr'** package.

I understand this question has been asked zillion times but after consulting Stack Overflow and other forums, I still cannot resolve my problem being an inexperienced R user.

Throughout the analysis, I successfully subsetted the data frame for all months except **'September'** and **'October'**.

When I run the code, the results for **'September'** and **'October'** display this error below:

```
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names). As checked this happens either if there is some space at the end of the variable name, or there are no values. However, no columns have missing values and the data frame has 536 observations.

I have rechecked the data frame for inconsistent errors but I cannot find any, I filled all empty cells with zero's, and I wondered if the problem is a row logicals vs row numbers vs row names issue.

After extensive research for many hours, I still cannot solve this problem!

Could anyone please help?

Many thanks in advance, I would be deeply appreciative!

**R Code:**

```
##Set the seed
  set.seed(45L)

##Change the format of the columns 

New_Blue$Year<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Year)
New_Blue$Month<-as.factor(New_Blue$Month)
New_Blue$Latitude<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Latitude)
New_Blue$Longitude<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Longitude)
New_Blue$Best<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Best)

##Structure of the data

str(New_Blue)

##Results 

      New_Blue$Year<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Year)
      New_Blue$Month<-as.factor(New_Blue$Month) 
      New_Blue$Latitude<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Latitude)
      New_Blue$Longitude<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Longitude)
      New_Blue$Best<-as.numeric(New_Blue$Best)
```

**Attempts to solve the problem**

```
##Is the problem the row logicals vs row numbers vs row names?

   New_Blue_Data <- New_Blue[1:536, ]
   New_Blue_Data[rep(TRUE, 536), ]

#Convert NA's to zero's

   New_Blue[is.na(New_Blue)] <- 0
```

**Subsetting the Data by Month:**

```
package(dplyr)


##Subset the data frame by the column 'Month'

January_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "January")
February_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "February")
March_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "March")
April_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "April")
May_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "May")
August_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "August")
September_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "September")
October_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "October")
November_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "November")
December_Whales<-subset(Blue, Month == "December")

##Error message

September_Whales
[1] Year      Month     Latitude  Longitude Best     
 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)   

October_Whales
[1] Year      Month     Latitude  Longitude Best     
 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

**Data Frame:**

```
structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), Month = structure(c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("April", "August", "August ", "December", 
"February", "January", "July ", "March", "May", "November", "November ", 
"October ", "September "), class = "factor"), Latitude = c(5.832, 
5.836, 5.83, 5.823, 5.823, 5.83, 5.803, 5.803, 5.886, 5.858, 
5.931, 5.931, 5.865, 5.761, 5.859, 5.911, 5.919, 5.82, 5.841, 
5.799, 5.776, 5.83, 5.797, 5.787, 5.795, 5.795, 5.807, 5.808, 
5.807, 5.811, 5.762, 5.74, 5.773, 5.846, 5.78, 5.816, 5.831, 
5.813, 5.785, 5.81, 5.819, 5.795, 5.801, 5.77, 5.853, 5.834, 
5.814, 5.799, 5.826, 5.826, 5.829, 5.834, 5.878, 5.862, 5.925, 
5.88, 5.867, 5.833, 5.8, 5.803, 5.809, 5.817, 5.847, 5.878, 5.879, 
5.842, 5.83, 5.834, 5.873, 5.786, 5.833, 5.821, 5.821, 5.836, 
5.836, 5.836, 5.828, 5.838, 5.828, 5.82, 5.8, 5.86, 5.841, 5.864, 
5.862, 5.901, 5.841, 5.844, 5.844, 5.843, 5.836, 5.838, 5.757, 
5.836, 5.869, 5.667, 5.818, 5.802, 5.8, 5.809, 5.725, 5.715, 
5.722, 5.674, 5.706, 5.679, 5.814, 5.85, 5.839, 5.839, 5.823, 
5.836, 5.832, 5.88, 5.781, 5.83, 5.875, 5.875, 5.782, 5.825, 
5.856, 5.849, 5.797, 5.767, 5.78, 5.812, 5.806, 5.827, 5.847, 
5.819, 5.804, 5.795, 5.867, 5.859, 5.811, 5.804, 5.865, 5.781, 
5.816, 5.82, 5.83, 5.815, 5.822, 5.808, 5.789, 5.822, 5.789, 
5.822, 5.87, 5.828, 5.824, 5.852, 5.864, 5.86, 5.845, 5.866, 
5.758, 5.805, 5.842, 5.838, 5.838, 5.783, 5.853, 5.868, 5.883, 
5.88, 5.803, 5.787, 5.811, 5.748, 5.826, 5.818, 5.783, 5.794, 
5.779, 5.818, 5.754, 5.811, 5.754, 5.846, 5.846, 5.834, 5.79, 
5.794, 5.885, 5.823, 5.787, 5.869, 5.76, 5.841, 5.783, 5.887, 
5.847, 5.82, 5.812, 5.789, 5.805, 5.797, 5.904, 5.806, 5.843, 
5.829, 5.841, 5.829, 5.839, 5.821, 5.806, 5.825, 5.836, 5.829, 
5.812, 5.825, 5.816, 5.821, 5.857, 5.799, 5.839, 5.841, 5.837, 
5.806, 5.855, 5.857, 5.849, 5.817, 5.805, 5.822, 5.853, 5.852, 
5.838, 5.873, 5.803, 5.817, 5.848, 5.826, 5.789, 5.796, 5.837, 
5.827, 5.83, 5.827, 5.823, 5.816, 5.822, 5.87, 5.863, 5.847, 
5.839, 5.774, 5.8, 5.834, 5.838, 5.826, 5.826, 5.835, 5.841, 
5.858, 5.363, 5.857, 5.856, 5.853, 5.857, 5.863, 5.835, 5.834, 
5.842, 5.846, 5.849, 5.838, 5.833, 5.828, 5.837, 5.838, 5.811, 
5.833, 5.869, 5.91, 5.863, 5.833, 5.831, 5.805, 5.826, 5.85, 
5.821, 5.81, 5.805, 5.824, 5.821, 5.846, 5.845, 5.806, 5.817, 
5.805, 5.819, 5.814, 5.819, 5.815, 5.812, 5.804, 5.814, 5.826, 
5.825, 5.807, 5.82, 5.812, 5.824, 5.798, 5.831, 5.81, 5.792, 
5.816, 5.802, 5.767, 5.761, 5.727, 5.76, 5.86, 5.789, 5.894, 
5.798, 5.848, 5.821, 5.829, 5.794, 0, 5.805, 5.734, 5.776, 5.749, 
5.83, 5.775, 5.824, 5.833, 5.82, 5.863, 5.835, 5.775, 5.761, 
5.753, 5.849, 5.839, 5.836, 5.801, 5.837, 5.84, 5.862, 5.843, 
5.859, 5.849, 5.863, 5.842, 5.838, 5.862, 5.846, 5.873, 5.844, 
5.84, 5.876, 5.844, 5.872, 5.84, 5.836, 5.84, 5.855, 5.829, 5.807, 
5.827, 5.837, 5.831, 5.875, 5.849, 5.841, 5.837, 5.803, 5.895, 
5.769, 5.825, 5.829, 5.827, 5.81, 5.865, 5.787, 5.807, 5.821, 
5.823, 5.848, 5.847, 5.902, 5.868, 5.868, 5.825, 5.837, 5.817, 
5.817, 5.813, 5.839, 5.839, 5.843, 5.825, 5.973, 5.856, 5.856, 
5.829, 5.844, 5.859, 5.839, 5.821, 5.832, 5.833, 5.842, 5.842, 
5.842, 5.842, 5.842, 5.842, 5.842, 5.842, 5.85, 5.807, 5.847, 
5.845, 5.842, 5.804, 5.793, 5.842, 5.822, 5.842, 5.844, 5.83, 
5.824, 5.822, 5.806, 5.789, 5.816, 5.804, 5.888, 5.831, 5.828, 
5.812, 5.822, 5.835, 5.835, 5.859, 5.811, 5.764, 5.782, 5.797, 
5.825, 5.824, 5.841, 5.871, 5.823, 5.841, 5.787, 5.812, 5.802, 
5.807, 5.758, 5.792, 5.789, 5.791, 5.826, 5.774, 5.809, 5.821, 
5.76, 5.747, 5.846, 5.827, 5.813, 5.815, 5.864, 5.823, 5.779, 
5.77, 5.815, 5.79, 5.811, 5.823, 5.789, 5.828, 5.842, 5.787, 
5.81, 5.794, 5.811, 5.737, 5.75, 5.737, 5.729, 5.775, 5.772, 
5.832, 5.832, 5.847, 5.748, 5.754, 5.824, 5.795, 5.769, 5.77, 
5.815, 5.738, 5.837, 5.822, 5.829, 5.812, 5.845, 5.82, 5.827, 
5.802, 5.821, 5.859, 5.88, 5.853, 5.854, 5.84, 5.805, 5.85, 5.848, 
5.844, 5.823, 5.877, 5.853, 5.78, 5.805, 5.844, 5.808, 5.84, 
5.842, 5.822, 5.819, 5.787, 5.788, 5.797, 5.869, 5.822), Longitude = c(80.35, 
80.326, 80.275, 80.281, 80.216, 80.112, 80.287, 80.17, 80.441, 
80.453, 80.431, 80.431, 80.469, 80.452, 80.502, 80.453, 80.441, 
80.28, 80.181, 80.177, 80.13, 80.533, 80.436, 80.442, 80.629, 
80.64, 80.712, 80.668, 80.611, 80.438, 80.493, 80.53, 80.501, 
80.519, 80.519, 80.619, 80.572, 80.581, 80.581, 80.507, 80.574, 
80.526, 80.52, 80.509, 80.468, 80.42, 80.369, 80.344, 80.39, 
80.447, 80.491, 80.403, 80.444, 80.47, 80.439, 80.422, 80.411, 
80.483, 80.433, 80.419, 80.503, 80.53, 80.503, 80.489, 80.558, 
80.621, 80.712, 80.746, 80.556, 80.675, 80.462, 80.496, 80.497, 
80.533, 80.45, 80.508, 80.53, 80.497, 80.503, 80.52, 80.463, 
80.491, 80.603, 80.424, 80.46, 80.445, 80.472, 80.503, 80.393, 
80.403, 80.421, 80.471, 80.418, 80.391, 80.607, 80.603, 80.449, 
80.435, 80.436, 80.428, 80.41, 80.374, 80.381, 80.554, 80.469, 
80.567, 80.634, 80.483, 80.548, 80.548, 80.605, 80.617, 80.554, 
80.474, 80.459, 80.486, 80.486, 80.486, 80.483, 80.378, 80.376, 
80.441, 80.405, 80.393, 80.423, 80.373, 80.492, 80.727, 80.611, 
80.39, 80.286, 80.451, 80.594, 80.435, 80.471, 80.448, 80.462, 
80.522, 80.471, 80.541, 80.526, 80.471, 80.455, 80.419, 80.411, 
80.448, 80.411, 80.448, 80.436, 80.383, 80.361, 80.42, 80.45, 
80.477, 80.488, 80.476, 80.492, 80.54, 80.602, 80.601, 80.617, 
80.572, 80.511, 80.475, 80.423, 80.366, 80.404, 80.432, 80.531, 
80.539, 80.456, 80.616, 80.667, 80.68, 80.662, 80.431, 80.544, 
80.381, 80.334, 80.559, 80.579, 80.59, 80.45, 80.654, 80.5, 80.671, 
80.553, 80.397, 80.604, 80.689, 80.65, 80.62, 80.818, 80.676, 
80.737, 80.609, 80.672, 80.71, 80.537, 80.611, 80.468, 80.434, 
80.459, 80.451, 80.443, 80.351, 80.369, 80.583, 80.491, 80.697, 
80.675, 80.768, 80.707, 80.671, 80.622, 80.705, 80.436, 80.424, 
80.441, 80.437, 80.544, 80.555, 80.535, 80.564, 80.543, 80.424, 
80.475, 80.434, 80.449, 80.443, 80.518, 80.498, 80.515, 80.43, 
80.436, 80.378, 80.404, 80.373, 80.391, 80.354, 80.286, 80.246, 
80.398, 80.26, 80.391, 80.364, 80.335, 80.492, 80.51, 80.442, 
80.432, 80.46, 80.46, 80.455, 80.425, 80.422, 80.475, 80.449, 
80.481, 80.442, 80.47, 80.458, 80.508, 80.507, 80.501, 80.528, 
80.528, 80.52, 80.493, 80.489, 80.5, 80.5, 80.557, 80.454, 80.464, 
80.448, 80.45, 80.477, 80.487, 80.509, 80.5, 80.463, 80.453, 
80.436, 80.483, 80.458, 80.461, 80.444, 80.459, 80.246, 80.176, 
80.151, 80.144, 80.15, 80.401, 80.488, 80.45, 80.382, 80.413, 
80.426, 80.431, 80.425, 80.388, 80.378, 80.448, 80.6, 80.334, 
80.665, 80.425, 80.596, 80.495, 80.634, 80.436, 80.352, 80.847, 
80.389, 80.404, 80.32, 80.394, 80.381, 80.433, 80.435, 80.276, 
80.16, 80.385, 80.274, 80.275, 80.262, 80.275, 80.331, 80.656, 
80.55, 80.494, 80.56, 80.27, 80.475, 80.481, 80.55, 80.58, 80.6, 
80.539, 80.59, 80.477, 80.463, 80.471, 80.513, 80.539, 80.519, 
80.464, 80.384, 80.387, 80.53, 80.527, 80.473, 80.527, 80.545, 
80.576, 80.401, 80.582, 80.534, 80.488, 80.518, 80.49, 80.507, 
80.489, 80.533, 80.555, 80.482, 80.45, 80.462, 80.478, 80.514, 
80.607, 80.484, 80.565, 80.358, 80.42, 80.429, 80.364, 80.386, 
80.399, 80.392, 80.29, 80.344, 80.497, 80.5, 80.415, 80.413, 
80.413, 80.473, 80.51, 80.394, 80.386, 80.318, 80.431, 80.414, 
80.416, 80.365, 80.455, 80.452, 80.461, 80.429, 80.459, 80.456, 
80.419, 80.412, 80.454, 80.387, 80.387, 80.421, 80.421, 80.421, 
80.421, 80.438, 80.438, 80.438, 80.438, 80.437, 80.437, 80.44, 
80.441, 80.442, 80.45, 80.349, 80.449, 80.502, 80.437, 80.585, 
80.539, 80.314, 80.462, 80.387, 80.34, 80.325, 80.427, 80.524, 
80.546, 80.609, 80.377, 80.432, 80.414, 80.449, 80.504, 80.368, 
80.402, 80.553, 80.592, 80.602, 80.537, 80.481, 80.558, 80.513, 
80.432, 80.432, 80.47, 80.515, 80.337, 80.427, 80.41, 80.447, 
80.514, 80.446, 80.459, 80.465, 80.416, 80.449, 80.427, 80.5, 
80.54, 80.49, 80.462, 80.472, 80.361, 80.231, 80.254, 80.216, 
80.18, 80.112, 80.074, 80.443, 80.454, 80.391, 80.409, 80.43, 
80.433, 80.645, 80.378, 80.283, 80.319, 80.399, 80.418, 80.412, 
80.412, 80.44, 80.435, 80.466, 80.488, 80.452, 80.441, 80.433, 
80.404, 80.392, 80.42, 80.487, 80.542, 80.605, 80.557, 80.402, 
80.47, 80.46, 80.417, 80.402, 80.427, 80.414, 80.41, 80.387, 
80.19, 80.319, 80.454, 80.12, 80.119, 80.391, 80.402, 80.314, 
80.304, 80.42, 80.403, 80.537, 80.44, 80.377, 80.492, 80.559, 
80.553, 80.554, 80.594, 80.32), Best = c(1L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 
15L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
11L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 9L, 14L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 
10L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
4L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 
3L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 
1L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 
10L, 10L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -536L
))
```

Comment: I am not aware of function `subset` in `dplyr`, maybe you meant `base::subset` ? It works fine for me on the data shared. However, instead of repeating steps with `subset`, you might want to consider to use `split`, `split(Blue, Blue$Month)`

Comment: There is no `date` column in your `dput`.

Comment: Sorry. That's my mistake, I removed the 'Date' column, 'typo'.  I am still really confused why the subset() function is producing the same <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) error. Do you think it might be the excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R one liner (separate into 12 dataframes - bring into global environment):

```
list2env(split(df, df$Month), .GlobalEnv)
```

Base R one liner (store 12 dataframes in a list):

```
# Split the dataframe up into a list of dataframes by the month: 

month_list <- split(df, df$Month)

# Name the dataframes appropriately: 

names(month_list) <- paste0(trimws(unique(df$Month), "both"), "_Whales")
```

Comment: Hey hello_friend. Thank you so much! I have managed to produce the separate 12 data frames. Could you please advise how to open an individual data frame? I named them 'January_Whales" etc.

Comment: View(month_list[[1]])

Comment: Or If they are in your global env using the first method View(January_Whales)

Comment: Also if you found the solution useful please upvote it and accept the answer :) enjoy R it is a very powerful language if you give it time !

Comment: Thank you hello_friend! You have been really helpful! Out of curiosity, how would I separate each data frame into separate objects using View(month_list[[1]])? I love learning new skills!

Comment: list2env(month_list, .GlobalEnv)